# Convert 8 points to a rectangle

Tags: c#, math, points

I draw 4 lines through 8 points on my picturebox which creates a rectangle.

```
            float xnum = 0.580481F;
            float ynum = 0.373782F;
            float znum = 0.419519F;
            float wnum = 0.219629F;

            PointF wnum1 = new PointF(1024, wnum * 1024);
            PointF wnum2 = new PointF(0, wnum * 1024);

            PointF xnum1 = new PointF(xnum * 1024, 1024);
            PointF xnum2 = new PointF(xnum * 1024, 0);

            PointF ynum1 = new PointF(1024, ynum * 1024);
            PointF ynum2 = new PointF(0, ynum * 1024);

            PointF znum1 = new PointF(znum * 1024, 1024);
            PointF znum2 = new PointF(znum * 1024, 0);

            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen1, wnum1, wnum2);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen1, znum1, znum2);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen1, xnum1, xnum2);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen1, ynum1, ynum2);
```

Is there a way to draw the rectangle directly out of my 8 points?

Comment: In general, a rectangle can be described by 4 points.  Conversely, 4 points may describe a rectangle, but it could be a general polygon.  One could make a rule to have a rectangle that surrounds the points in some ways, depending onthe scenario.   Why do you use 8 points?

Comment: Do you mean a planar rectangle?  It looks like you have 4 dimensions, so is this about a hyper-cube or volume or something?

Comment: In addition to @JosephDoggie comments - what you are planning to use to draw those - WPF, WinForms, something else? So far question is tagged with just "math" implying you need some help with related math rather than drawing... but you need to explain much better how you want those 4 values / 8 points to be converted to points on a 2d surface... Most frameworks give you way to draw axis-aligned rectangle by two points/point and size... but 8 points are tricky.

Comment: A pair of points makes a line and a pair of (non-parallel) lines has a crossing. You will have to calculate those 4 crossing points. Plenty of examples out there..

Comment: Hi Alexei and Joseph!
Joseph I use 8 points because in first step I've drawed the rectangle  I want by the 4 lines (as you see on the screen above so I needed 8 points). Now I want to draw the rectangle directly without the lines.
@Alexei I understand and I'm sorry about the math-tag mistake. I use WindowsForms. I think I dont need 8 points to draw the rectangle. I only need 4 points (each one where the lines cross each other which is 4 times on the screen above) but I dont know how to calculate these 4 points.

Comment: @TaW "crossing points" is what I need, yes! I'll search for that.

Comment: An alternative term is ['intersection'.](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&ei=9dcuYJDBCPeajLsPy-q26AQ&q=c%23+line+intersection&oq=c%23+line+intersection&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIECAAQQzIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB4yBggAEAgQHjIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB46CggAELADEEMQiwM6CAgAEAgQBxAeUIbdA1jF3wNg-eADaAFwAngAgAH7AYgB_QOSAQUzLjAuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQq4AQLAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjQj4G2rPTuAhV3DWMBHUu1DU0Q4dUDCAw&uact=5)

Comment: Are those lines always either horizontal or vertical? That would make calculating those intersections much easier!

Comment: Please mark on the image where the points are, otherwise it makes it hard to show you the correct code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To draw a rectangle you need four points.  What you're asking is to find the intersection of a set of lines described by eight different points, and draw the resulting polygon.  When phrased like that, it becomes a matter of working through the math:

```csharp
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (var pen1 = new Pen(Color.Black))
    {
        float xnum = 0.580481F;
        float ynum = 0.373782F;
        float znum = 0.419519F;
        float wnum = 0.219629F;

        PointF wnum1 = new PointF(1024, wnum * 1024);
        PointF wnum2 = new PointF(0, wnum * 1024);

        PointF xnum1 = new PointF(xnum * 1024, 1024);
        PointF xnum2 = new PointF(xnum * 1024, 0);

        PointF ynum1 = new PointF(1024, ynum * 1024);
        PointF ynum2 = new PointF(0, ynum * 1024);

        PointF znum1 = new PointF(znum * 1024, 1024);
        PointF znum2 = new PointF(znum * 1024, 0);

        // Given the four lines, find the intersection points that mark the corners of the polygon
        PointF[] points = new PointF[]
        {
            LineLineIntersection(wnum1, wnum2, xnum1, xnum2),
            LineLineIntersection(ynum1, ynum2, xnum1, xnum2),
            LineLineIntersection(ynum1, ynum2, znum1, znum2),
            LineLineIntersection(wnum1, wnum2, znum1, znum2),
        };
        e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(pen1, points);
    }
}

static PointF LineLineIntersection(PointF line1pt1, PointF line1pt2, PointF line2pt1, PointF line2pt2)
{
    // Calculate the formula for the first line
    float a1 = line1pt2.Y - line1pt1.Y;
    float b1 = line1pt1.X - line1pt2.X;
    float c1 = a1 * (line1pt1.X) + b1 * (line1pt1.Y);

    // Calculate the formula for the second line
    float a2 = line2pt2.Y - line2pt1.Y;
    float b2 = line2pt1.X - line2pt2.X;
    float c2 = a2 * (line2pt1.X) + b2 * (line2pt1.Y);

    float determinant = a1 * b2 - a2 * b1;

    if (determinant == 0)
    {
        // The two lines are parallel, there is no intersection (or they're the same line)
        throw new Exception("Parallel lines");
    }
    else
    {
        // Calculate the point of intersection
        float x = (b2 * c1 - b1 * c2) / determinant;
        float y = (a1 * c2 - a2 * c1) / determinant;
        return new PointF(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Yay for using the proper line-line intersection algorithm based on the `(a,b,c)` homogeneous coordinates of a line.